# amp draw on a Honda abs modulator

Tags: honda, abs

Does anyone know what the amp draw is on a Honda abs modulator when the modulator is engaged? The fuse is rated for 30 amps so it has be to less than 30.

If no one knows the Honda specific draw, what would the amp draw for an abs modulator (4 door midsize sedan) in general.

I’m using an autel 808 to do an abs modulator bleed.  The test runs a quarter as long as it should.  I’m trying to find why the autel stops the test early.

Edits

I used a current clamp while running the test and the ABS draws about 26 Amps.

The Battery is in great condition.  I used a Schumacher Battery Load Tester and the battery is excellent.  The autel instructions suggest using an external 12v source.  I attached a 1000A Peak 10800mAh 12V Car Jump Starter but I don't think it engaged.  I think the jump starter does a diagnostic when first connected and if the voltage is good, the jump starter does not engage.

As a work-around, I ran the test 3 times for a total of around 30 seconds.  The bleed after the final run produced no bubbles.

Comment: Is the car battery on its last legs or in good condition? When commanding the abs unit to perform bleeding procedures, it's imperative to have a good battery otherwise drawing any current above several amps may not work with a battery of unknown life. If you can connect an automatic battery charger that varies its output, this may help the battery maintain power or connect another battery in parallel. Electronics can have its own 'heart attack' when less than ideal power drops below a certain voltage.